# Getting angular form validation to work without using ngSubmit

Tags: validation, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is a simple form with an input that is required:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="add-entry" press-enter="add_entry()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="amount" required />
        <!-- <input type="submit" value="Add" /> -->
    </form>
</div>
```

The form uses a custom pressEnter directive because I'm reluctant to use an `<input type="submit" />` in my markup, even if I can hide it with absolute positioning and whatnot (using `ngSubmit` instead of `pressEnter` would require one of these to fire the expression).

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('pressEnter', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
      if(event.which === 13) {
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.$eval(attrs.pressEnter);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

The problem now is that the `required` attribute is also not taken into account without `ngSubmit`. See http://jsfiddle.net/w6QHD/12/ -- you can see that pressing enter on an empty input still fires `add_entry()`. The form is validated only when using `ngSubmit` instead of `pressEnter` and uncommenting the `<input type="submit">`.

How do I make form validation work without using `ngSubmit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear whether you want to rely on HTML5 validation or on AngularJS validation.
If it's the Angular validation that you want to use than you may simply use [FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController) to trigger the validation and error messages:

```html
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="form" press-enter="add_entry()" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="amount" ng-model="amount" required />
    <span ng-show="submitted && form.amount.$error.required">Amount is required</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.add_entry = function() {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        if($scope.form.$valid){
            console.log("Entry added");
        }
    }
};
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vy6NQ/)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it was the HTML5 validation that was triggering the original error messages.